# Allow download_url for lan addresses

Tags: wp-cli, configuration, http-api

I'm hosting a wp site on my own server (at home) and I would like to use wp cli to import media from my own computer.
On my computer, I have a web server and I asks to wp-cli to import media from "http://192.168.0.2/wpTemp/media.txt".

It fails! After investigations, it is due to the ip address which is not recognized as "safe" by download_url() => wp_safe_remote_get().

Is there a way to configure wp to allow only 192.168.0.2 ? and keep the protection for everything else.
(I'll also need to know where to put the modification, I don't want to redo the modification after wp update).

Thank you for your time!

The code of the problem: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_http_validate_url/ line 566 return false and marks the url as invalid.

Comment: Are you using the `wp import` command to import? According to [the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/import/) you should be providing a path to a WXR file, not a URL.

Comment: wp media import - documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/media/import/) last example is using url.
I spend a lot of time to know the real problem. The error message says "You provided a non valid URL". If I activate my VPN on my own computer and use the vpn ip address it works. I used "wp eval" to call the proper function of wp code.

Comment: Is the server you're running the command on and the server with the file the same server?

Answer (score 3):

to allow this IP as safe, use this filter

```
add_filter("http_request_host_is_external", function ($is, $host, $url) {

    if ("192.168.0.2" === $host) {
        $is = TRUE;
    }


    return $is;

}, 10, 3);
```

Comment: Where in the wp code shoud I put this code ?

Comment: I think that the better place for that is in a plugin https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

Comment: Thank you very much, it works. Shame! Shame! Why should I touch code in order to import content from another site? Grrrrrr